# Is there any way to override foreign key delete protection in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a webapp that has been running for many years with a bunch of models  interconnected via foreign keys with `on_delete=models.PROTECT`. That is what we want for normal operations. However, now I need to delete old data from the system (e.g. anything more then 2 years old), since things are starting to slow down due to the volume of data.

Is there any way, as a one time thing, for me to override the `on_delete` protection?

Answer (score 1):

A thought: Do a custom migration that uses 1) `migrations.AlterField()` to set to a logical on_delete for these sorts of deletes (`CASCADE`), 2) use `migrations.RunPython` to call a function that does the record deletion based on the criteria you choose and then 3) `migrations.AlterField` to set it back to normal after the migration is over. Obviously, test against a QA dump first!